# Creating object instance

Tags: ruby

Is there a difference between

```
x = Class.new( or method)
x.method
```

and

```
Class.new(or method) do |x|
x.method
end
```

Comment: When you say `Class.new` do you literally mean `Class.new` or are you using `Class` as a place holder for the actual class?

Comment: I mean actual class. For example File.open()

Answer (score 6):

```
x = SomeClass.new
x.some_method
```

This first creates an instance of `SomeClass` (calling `initialize` with no arguments). It then calls the method `some_method` on that instance.

```
SomeClass.new do |x|
  x.some_method
end
```

This creates an instance of `SomeClass`, calling `initialize` with a block as its argument. That block takes one argument and calls `some_method` on that argument. Whether and how often the block will be called and what the argument will be depends entirely on what `SomeClass`'s initialize method does.

In many cases the pattern

```
SomeClass.some_creation_method do |x|
  x.some_method
end
```

is used, so that `some_creation_method` creates a `SomeClass` instance, yields it to the block and then frees all the resources used by that instance after the block finishes (e.g. it could close file handles, delete temporary files etc.). This is what `File.open` does.

---

In the case where the class in question is literally `Class` the block will be `class_eval`ed on the newly created class, i.e.

```
c = Class.new do
  some_code
end
```

is equivalent to

```
c = Class.new
c.class_eval do
  some_code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the class. e.g. for `File` objects,

```
File.open("foo.txt", "wb") do |f|
  f.write("x")
end
```

the file handle will be closed automatically when the block exits. But that's only the idiom, in general the class defines the semantics, and chooses if it supplies the variant with the block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example showing that the two are not equivalent. They would only be equivalent if the `initialize` method of your class called `yield(self)` at the end.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize( name )
    @name = name
  end
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi, I am #{@name}"
  end
end

x = MyClass.new( "Bob" )
x.say_hi
#=> Hi, I am Bob

MyClass.new( "Jim" ) do |x|
  x.say_hi
end
#=> (nothing prints out)
```

In the second example, I pass a block to `new`, but since my `initialize` method doesn't do anything with the block, the contents of the block are never run.